# Java Encode and decode string without forward or backward slash

Tags: java, base64, aes

I have the code that encode and decode string.

When I input "9" encrypt method return "9iCOC73F/683bf5WRJDnKQ=="

The problem is that when I encode String sometimes it will return encoded string with **(/ or \ )** and I want to remove that **(/ or \ )** from String.

So how can i achieve with my encrypt and decrypt both method.

```
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class EncryptDecryptAESAlgo {
    private static final String ALGO = "AES";
    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { 'A', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
            'n', 'o', 'p' };

    public String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        String encryptedValue = "";
        try {
            Key key = generateKey();
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
            encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
            return encryptedValue;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        String decryptedValue = "";
        try {
            Key key = generateKey();
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
            byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
            decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
            return decryptedValue;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    private Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
    }
}
```

I am using Java.

Comment: Please add input and output with your expectation

Comment: @Sanjeev when i input "9" encrypt method return "9iCOC73F/683bf5WRJDnKQ=="

Comment: Why is that a problem? "/" is part of the base64 charset. You cannot really avoid that strings contain that char. You could replace it but then you run into other issues ...

Comment: Use Base58, Base36, Base32, Base16, Base10, Base2, Base1? Or you could simply replace the offending character with a more suitable character.

Answer (score 15):

Use Base64 "URL-safe" encoding as described in [IETF RFC 4648 Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5). This replaces the `+` and `/` characters with `-` and `_` respectively. Instantiate those encoder/decoders as follows:

```
java.util.Base64.Encoder encoder = java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder();
java.util.Base64.Decoder decoder = java.util.Base64.getUrlDecoder();
```